# Can we reliably pre-increment/decrement rvalues?

Tags: c++, rvalue, pre-increment

For example, `std::vector<int>::iterator it = --(myVec.end());`. This works in GCC 4.4 but I have heard a rumor that it's not portable.

Comment: Do you have a link where it discusses it not being portable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It will only work if `std::vector<int>::iterator` is an object type with `operator++` a member function.  If it's a scalar type (e.g. `int *`), or `operator++` is a non-member function, it will fail.

> #### 5.3.2 Increment and decrement [expr.pre.incr]
>
> 1 - The operand of prefix `++` is modified by adding `1` [...]. *The operand shall be a modifiable lvalue.* [...]
>   2 - [...] The requirements on the operand of prefix `--` [...] are [...] the same as those of prefix `++`. [...]

Non-const non-static member functions can be called on temporary objects (since they have non-`const` object type, per 9.3.2p3), but an lvalue reference parameter in a non-member function cannot bind to a temporary (13.3.3.1.4p3).

```
struct S { S &operator++(); };
struct T { }; T &operator++(T &);
typedef int U;

++S();  // OK
++T();  // fails
++U();  // fails
```

This means that it's nothing to do with the compiler, but rather the standard library; as you've observed libstdc++ is implemented with `std::vector<int>::iterator` an object type with member `operator++`, but your code could easily be compiled with the same compiler and a different standard library where `std::vector<int>::iterator` is `int *`, in which case it would fail.

`std::vector`, `std::array` and `std::string` are the only container templates that can sensibly be implemented with scalar (pointer) iterators, but that doesn't mean that calling `++` on other containers' iterators is safe; they could have non-member `operator++` as `T` above.

To make an iterator to the before-the-end element, use `std::prev`:

```
std::vector<int>::iterator it = std::prev(myVec.end());
```

`std::prev` and `std::next` are new in C++11, but are easily implementable in C++03.

Comment: I checked the standard and didn't see where a scalar rvalue cannot be pre-decremented. Do you happen to know where that is?

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: you can test it out easily `++(1+1)`.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod it's 5.3.2p1; I've added a quote above.

Answer (score 6):

No that won't work in general.

In C++11 we have: `auto it = std::prev(myVec.end());`, which works reliably.

Boost has a similar function if you're in C++03, though it's trivial to write altogether:

```
template <typename BidirectionalIterator>
BidirectionalIterator
    prev(BidirectionalIterator x,
         typename std::iterator_traits<BidirectionalIterator>::difference_type n = 1)
{
    std::advance(x, -n);
    return x;
}
```

Keep in mind you need at least one element in the range for this to make sense.

---

Here's an example of how your method won't work in general, consider this stripped-down `std::vector<>`:

```
#include <iterator>

namespace std_exposition
{
    template <typename T>
    struct vector
    {
        // this is compliant:
        typedef T* iterator;

        iterator end()
        {
            return std::end(data);
        }

        T data[4];
    };

    // manually implemented std::prev:
    template <typename BidirectionalIterator>
    BidirectionalIterator
        prev(BidirectionalIterator x,
             typename std::iterator_traits<BidirectionalIterator>::difference_type n = 1)
    {
        std::advance(x, -n);
        return x;
    }
}
```

Test program:

```
int main()
{
    std_exposition::vector<int> myVec;

    // Won't compile (method in question):
    auto it0 = --(myVec.end());

    // Compiles
    auto it1 = std::prev(myVec.end());
    auto it2 = std_exposition::prev(myVec.end());
}
```

---

There is a corresponding `std::next` as well, implemented here:

```
template <typename BidirectionalIterator>
BidirectionalIterator
    next(BidirectionalIterator x,
         typename std::iterator_traits<BidirectionalIterator>::difference_type n = 1)
{
    std::advance(x, n);
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed not portable, because there's no way to know whether `myVec.end()` returns an object of class type with operator `--` overloaded by a member function or something else (maybe even a regular raw ponter). In the former case the overloaded `--` will compile (operators overloaded by member functions can be applied to rvalues), while in the latter case it will not.